# Python looping through nest lists

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

I'm trying to iterate through a nested list, as an example:

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8'], ['9', '10']]
```

my desired output is

```
[['1', '2'], ['2', '3'], ['3', '4'], ['4', '5'], ['6', '7'], ['7', '8'], ['9', '10']]
```

I've been able to use a function to give me the result for the first list

```
[['1', '2'], ['2', '3'], ['3', '4'], ['4', '5']]
```

but haven't been able to iterate through all of the nested lists. I'm sure there is an easy loop I can add to this but I haven't been able to get one to work.

Comment: Use [`chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and apply your function on return of this function.

Comment: could you add what you tried? people could suggest how you can improve existing code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip`ping to get the pairs and then concatenate using `chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
data = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8'], ['9', '10']]
result = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(x, x[1:]) for x in data))
```

Comment: There's `from_iterable()` which fit's even better: `list(chain.from_iterable(zip(x, x[1:]) for x in data))`

Comment: @OlvinRoght: good point, this way even one could even easily process the whole sequence without the need to having it all in memory at the same time (only the single sublists will be)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
output = []
for i in l:    
    for index,j in enumerate(i):
        if len(i) != index+1:
            output.append([j,i[index+1]])    
output
```

output is:

```
[['1', '2'],
 ['2', '3'],
 ['3', '4'],
 ['4', '5'],
 ['6', '7'],
 ['7', '8'],
 ['9', '10']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8'], ['9', '10']]
def my_func (curr_list):
    return [[curr_list[i-1], curr_list[i]] for i in range(1, len(curr_list))]
ret = []
for i in [my_func(i) for i in my_list]: ret += i
print(ret)
```

```
[['1', '2'], ['2', '3'], ['3', '4'], ['4', '5'], ['6', '7'], ['7', '8'], ['9', '10']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a iterable sequence

```py
def chain(lst):
    for sequence in lst:
        for index in range(len(sequence)-1):
            yield sequence[index:index+2]

lst = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8'], ['9', '10']]

print(list(chain(lst)))
```